# imresize error using OpenCV 2.4.10 and Python 2.7.10

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to resize an image with OpenCV 2.4.10 and Python 2.7.10.

This works:

```
resized_patch = cv2.resize(patch, (3, 50, 50))
```

However, I'm interested in using INTER_AREA interpolation. Following the [documentation for Python](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize), I tried:

```
dst = numpy.zeros((3, 50, 50))
resized_patch = cv2.resize(patch, (3, 50, 50), dst=dst, fx=0, fy=0, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

However, the error I'm getting from the cv2.resize line is:

```
TypeError: 'function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)'
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a 2D size for `dst.size()` not 3D :

```
resized_patch = cv2.resize(patch, (3, 50, 50), dst=dst, fx=0, fy=0, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
                                      ^^^ #here
```

Comment: Thanks! And is there no nice way to resize all 3 dimensions simultanously?

Comment: @angela Welcome, actually I have not any idea but this question my be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27619936/downsampling-large-3d-image-in-numpy

Answer (score -1):

Please use this "resize" instead of "cv2.resize";

```
from skimage.transform import resize
```

Comment: This should probably be a comment.